# a simple function between deferred functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each, deferred

Let's say I want to Login and Logout by clearing the cookies with this

```
function clearCookies() {
   ...
}

function login(username,password) {
   $.post(...).then(function(result){
       if(result == 1) {
           create();
       }
       else {
           login(username, password);
       }
   })
}

function create() {
     $.post(...).then(function(result){
         // create
     })
}
```

Where should I insert the `clearCookies` function when I loop through the usernames.

```
var data = [{"username":"_iamnumber4","password":"four"},{"username":"superman","password":"fantasic"}]

var promises = [];
$.each(data, function(k,v){
    promises.push(login(v.username, v.password));
});

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
      console.log('all done');
});
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for (to me at least)

Comment: It would belong in the success callback defined in `login()`, or you would have to implement support for the progress event and run it there.

Comment: i'll update the question again

Comment: in that case what should I do.

Comment: I don't think you can do it correctly using a loop like that, there's no way to guarantee that each create will be called with the correct cookies. Also, your login function should be returning `$.post`, currently your $.when will resolve instantly rather than when they are all done.

Comment: any work around for that?